# wordpress error : Your connection to this server has been blocked in this server's firewall

Tags: php, wordpress

WP developers may have seen this error

"Your connection to this server has been blocked in this server's firewall.
You need to contact the server owner for further information.
Your blocked IP address is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

it is for md_security but why it starts coming suddenly without any change in code. Im using wordpress 4+ version.

I fixed it by disabling mod security for my domain.I'm looking for a safe fix. disabling mod security welcomes CSRF security issues.

Comment: How do you know that there haven't been any changes to the code? Are you sure the site hasn't been hacked?

Comment: Hi Cale, No change in code, not even hacked. My observation is while I browse my wp site its fine. but while I try to open wp-admin or user my ecommerce cart functionality it blocks every time. I fixed it by disabling mod security for my domain.I'm looking for a safe fix.  disabling mod security welcomes CSRF security issues.